# iOS purgeIdleCellConnections

Tags: ios, xcode, nsurlconnection

I'm getting a list of purgeIdleCellConnections shortly after downloading a lot of png images from the internet from a model class in the app.

**Is this a threat to the application? It doesn't freeze up. Should I manually be closing connections?**

Thanks!

xcode 4.2.1, ARC, deploying to ios 5.0+

EDIT: I'm seeing the list in my console. Also, I only see it when testing from my phone on a 3G network, not on wifi. Doesn't happen in simulator either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have no idea where you're seeing "a list of purgeIdleCellConnections".

If you mean in the Organizer console, it's probably normal: You've just stopped downloading stuff, so presumably there are now a bunch of idle cell network connections which can be turned off to save power (that's my take on it, anyway).

Comment: i'm seeing it in console. and i only see it when i'm using 3g, not when using wifi. any idea why that could be?

Comment: Because you don't use the cellular network for the image downloads when on Wi-Fi.